# How to use a const defined in onMount to send a websocket message

Tags: websocket, svelte

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let socket
    
    onMount(async () => {
        const socket = new WebSocket("ws://51.255.44.20:8001/test")
        socket.addEventListener("open", ()=> {
            console.log("Opened")
        })
        socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            console.log(event.data);
        })
    });

    function onSendMessage() {
        console.log("I am trying to send a message");
        if (socket){
                console.log("Sending a message");
                if (socket.readyState <= 1) {
                    socket.send("test message");
                }
        }
    }

</script>

<div class="container h-full mx-auto flex justify-center items-center">
    <div>
        <button on:click={onSendMessage}>
            Send Message
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to send a message to the websocket client opened. I added a `let socket` at the beginning. Though, in the console I can only read:

```
 I am trying to send a message
```

So console never prints "Sending a message". I guess that socket object does not exist, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const socket` ["shadows"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the outer declaration, you are creating a new variable in a more limited scope and the outer one remains undefined. Just remove the `const` to set the outer one.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to point is that you don't need to use `onMount` for code that only runs once. `onMount` will make sure that the code only runs once AFTER the component has rendered for the first time. For your code, you can simply remove `onMount`. The code will also run only once, on component creation, and you don't have to worry about repeating it (at least not more than with `onMount`)

```html
<script>
  const socket = new WebSocket("ws://51.255.44.20:8001/test");

  socket.addEventListener("open", ()=> {
    console.log("Opened");
  });

  socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    console.log(event.data);
  });

  function onSendMessage() {
    console.log("I am trying to send a message");
    if (socket){
      console.log("Sending a message");
      if (socket.readyState <= 1) {
        socket.send("test message");
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This will cause issues with server-side rendering.

Comment: I tried that already and didn't work. As far as I understood, Websocket client can only be opened in the client browser, so in order to ensure that the code is executed there either it has to be written at the onMount or use browser (import { browser } from '$app/environment';)

Comment: @H.B. it isn't pointed in the question that he's looking for SSR or is using SvelteKit. However, just like Daniel wrote, if he's indeed using SvelteKit, the correct approach would be to use the `browser` variable from $app/environment instead of using onMount. onMount will delay socket creation for no reason, since there's no need to wait for the component to render once before initializing a websocket connection.